# MySQL Find all user with the same ip in the same day

Tags: mysql

I have a user login history table, shown here:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip       | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date     | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to get a query that can select all the user that share the same ip on the same day.

As requested in the comment i expect this result when i run this query

```
username        ip              date

// This 3 are linked (same ip, same day, distinct username)
Test1           10.10.20.20     28/12/2015 10:50:30
AnotherUser     10.10.20.20     27/12/2015 14:20:20
User3           10.10.20.20     28/12/2015 22:50:10

// This 2 are linked (same ip, same day, distinct username)
User159         30.10.20.20     28/12/2015 10:50:30
User156         30.10.20.20     28/12/2015 13:45:30
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Dont clear can you give your expected output ?

Comment: Why did you accept an answer with such markedly different output from what you seemed to be trying to achieve? Oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ip, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT username), DATE(`date`)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ip, DATE(`date`)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT username) > 1
```

**On a side note:**

`Date` is a **[keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)** in MYSQL. So try to avoid it as column name.

Comment: @Strawberry:- It is. Please check the link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html And also in MySQL 5.6: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Strawberry:- I am not sure whats your point! And for sure one must avoid using `Date` as column name. Its quite confusing and that is what my intention was  :)

Comment: It's a keyword, but it ain't 'reserved' (R) - which is why this query will work just fine without the backticks. That's my point.

Comment: @Strawberry:- Point taken :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
SELECT `ip`, GROUP_CONCAT(`username` SEPARATOR ' \t '), `date`
FROM Table
GROUP BY `date`, `ip`
```